# How to convert list type in Java hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, list

In java application I use hibernate criteria queries, 
for example:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Any.class);
...

List<?> list = criteria.list();
```

and I definetly know that result list contains only objects of type **Any** but 
I don't know if it's possible to get list of type defined above?

In this case, if I want to use foreach it's necessary to convert type from object to type **Any**

```
for(Object object : list) {
    ...
    ((Any)object).
    ...
}
```

Or if I need to get an array I have to do something like this:

```
list.toArray(new Any[]{});
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate does not support generics. So the following code is the "best" you get:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Any> resultList = criteria.list();

for(Any any : resultList){ ... }
```

Maybe

```
List<Any> resultList = criteria.list();
for(Any any : resultList){ ... }
```

is better as the type warning is still there. This convertion cannot be checked by the compiler. So the warning is ok.